# PHP - data not properly used from GET parameter

Tags: php, get

This is my code:

```
file_put_contents('ip.txt', $ip); // ip is 62.227.217.95 and is saved correctly into ip.txt file

$returned_content = get_data('https://xxx:xxx@geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/' . $ip);

file_put_contents('content.txt', $returned_content); // file is empty, nothign saved
```

You can see what's the problem in the comments.

BUT when I put the ip directly instead of from GET parameter:

```
file_put_contents('ip.txt', $ip); // ip is 62.227.217.95 and is saved correctly into ip.txt file

$returned_content = get_data('https://xxx:xxx@geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/62.227.217.95');

file_put_contents('content.txt', $returned_content); // content is written correctly, everything fine.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I also tried `urldecode($ip)`

Please help

Comment: try without space /city/'.$ip);

Comment: Still the same..

Comment: If `$ip` contained _exactly_ `62.227.217.95` then this would be fine. There's nothing wrong with the code sample you shared. This means that the variable doesn't exactly contain what you think it does.

Comment: What does get_data do? can you put a `var_dump($argument)` inside that function and see what you are getting?

Comment: `hexdump -C ip.txt` and look for non-printing chars.

Comment: Evert this is the reason I saved $ip into file!! To be sure it's 100% correct, I am also wondering why the hell this isn't working. Maybe because I send it from android app? But WHY is it saved into ip.txt correctly then??

Comment: @sammitch you gave me the idea what was wrong, there are any damn invisible characters, preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $ip) solved the problem. Type it as solution and I accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were invisible chars, I solved it with: `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $ip)`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
get_data('https://xxx:xxx@geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/'.$ip.'');
```

or

```
$url = 'https://xxx:xxx@geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/'.$ip;  
get_data($url);
```